# Can't Add a Second User Button Programatically

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to programatically add multiple buttons to multiple worksheets, but it's only working for one of the sheets ("Sheet1"). Below is my code, I'm wondering if there's anything else that I can do which will enable me to add buttons to Sheet2 and any others. Thanks!

```
Sub button_maker(wb As Workbook)
Dim r As Range
Set r = Selection
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Buttons.Add(27, 30, 100, 20).Select
    With Selection
        .OnAction = "'" & wb.Name & "'" & "!" & "Button9_click"
        .Characters.Text = "Input Sales"
    End With
r.Select

End Sub


Sub button_maker2(wb As Workbook)

Dim d As Range
Set d = Selection
    wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Buttons.Add(1065, 1, 60, 20).Select
    With Selection
        .Characters.Text = "Input Sales"
        .OnAction = "'" & wb.Name & "'" & "!" & "Button9_click"
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Sub test()
    button_maker ThisWorkbook, Sheets(1)
    button_maker ThisWorkbook, Sheets(2)
End Sub
Sub button_maker(wb As Workbook, Ws As Worksheet)
Dim r As Range
Dim Bt As Shape

    Set Bt = Ws.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlButtonControl, 27, 30, 100, 20)
    With Bt
        .OnAction = "'" & wb.Name & "'" & "!" & "Button9_click"
        .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Input Sales"
    End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Code below will add a button on the 3 first worksheets of your active workbook.

```
Option Explicit

Sub button_maker()
Dim Bt0 As Button
Dim Wb0 As Workbook: Set Wb0 = ActiveWorkbook
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 3
    Set Bt0 = Wb0.Sheets(i).Buttons.Add(27, 30, 100, 20)
    Bt0.OnAction = ""
    Bt0.Caption = "Input Sales"
    'Bt0.Name = "" if you want to name it for future reference
Next i

End Sub
```

I'm not sure what your goal is exactly but you can play with this code and adapt it to your needs.